# Value matching by %in%

Tags: r

I have created a loop where i go through a dataframe where i match values with another dataframe.
I want to find matches by two variables. The two dataframes contain the same variables.

for example:

```
X1 <- c(4247857)
X2 <- c(4.66)
dataframe1 <- data.frame(X1, X2)

X1 <- c(4247850, 4247888, 4247857, 4020051)
X2 <- c(4.55, 3.66, 4.66, 3.05)
dataframe2 <- data.frame(X1, X2)

tempvar <- dataframe1[1, "X2"]
dataframe1[1,"X2"] %in% dataframe2[dataframe2$X2 == tempvar, "X2"]
```

The results here are:

```
dataframe1[1,"X2"] %in% dataframe2[dataframe2$X2 == tempvar, "X2"]
TRUE
```

This is what i want but the outcome with my real data is:

```
 dataframe1[3, "X2"]
 3.05

dataframe2[dataframe2$X2 == tempvar, "X2"]
3.05
3.05
3.05
4.66
3.05
4.66
4.66
3.05
4.66
3.05
4.66

dataframe1[3,"X2"] %in% dataframe2[dataframe2$X2 == tempvar, "X2"]
    FALSE
```

What could be the reason i get a FALSE here?

Comment: Please update your question with some more of your data and a precise expected output, as to have a clear reproducible example.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: updated the example data. 4 observations where i check observation 3 that should match but the outcomes gives false.

Comment: *I want to find matches by two variables.*...which ones?? Also please go through the links I gave you and make proper reproducible examples

Comment: The problem is that when i build an example it produces a TRUE. But my real data gives a false. Its basically the same so if you could just look at my outputs to detect what might be the reason for it to give a FALSE.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. With the data you provided `dataframe2[dataframe2$X2 == tempvar, "X2"]` is `4.66` and `dataframe1[3, "X2"]` is `NA` which means the result `FALSE` is correct. Provide more data (e.g. `dput(dataframe1);dput(dataframe2)`) if you want to be helped.

Comment: yes forgot to change the 3 in 1 there, I will edit it now and it is reproducable. The example gives a true but the real data not. I can't give out my real data since it is confidential information.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you can go for `merge` which is much faster and efficient way than using loops:

```
# create a flag to see if it works correctly
df1$flag <- 1

# merge the data
df3 <- merge(df, df1[,c('X2','X3','flag')], by = c('X2','X3'), all.x = T)

  X2   X3 X1  X4 flag
1  A 0.10  1 yes   NA
2  B 3.66  2  no   NA
3  B 4.66  1 yes    1
4  C 3.05  1 yes   NA

# now you can do the next step on df3
```

Comment: What i try to do is find rows of dataframe 1 where I find the same person(X1) and value(X2) in dataframe 2. Then give X3 of dataframe1 the same value as dataframe2 and add that (changed) observation to dataframe2.

Comment: Okay, so in dataframe2 it value for X3 for X1=1, X2=A will change to 3.05 ?

Comment: lets say for the the output of your example data:
If dataframe1 X1 and X2 = dataframe X1 and X2 then change dataframe1 X3 to the value of dataframe2 X3.

I updated my example data so you can run that one which produces a false where it has a match.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't figure out what causes the mismatch but I have found a workaround for it.

instead of checking 2 variables like the example I now use a semi_join for each variable and check if those are the same. This gives me a true on all variables like this:

```
temp <- semi_join(dataframe2, dataframe1[i,], by= "X1") 
temp2 <-semi_join(temp, dataframe1, by= "X2")
if(datafram1[i,"X2"] == unique(temp2$X2))
```